# Inorganic IUPAC for Compounds with bridged ligands?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, coordination-compounds

[image]

Can we use  bis(tetraammine) instead of octaammine is the 2nd example ?

As in the 1st example they used  bis(pentaammine)  and also in the 3 one the used bis(carbonylcyclopentadienyliron)

Comment: Btw, IUPAC Red Book 2005 mentions probably the same complex ion 1. [{Cr(NH₃)₅}₂(μ-OH)\]⁵⁺, but the name contains complex net charge instead of metal oxidation state: μ-hydroxido-bis(pentaamminechromium)(5+). Most importantly, the parentheses seem to be incorrect in the question.

Comment: @mykhal  Yes I think the parentheses is incorrect It should be like the 3rd example , but still I am confused .

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of a similar ligand and it can be named in three ways.
All you have to do is to put hydroxido/hydroxo in place of superoxido.

[image]

So yes, bridged ligands can be named in a few ways, combining any amount of recurring atoms separately, but most common used would be (if the LHS and RHS are the same) μ-amido-μ-hydroxidobis(tetraammine)dicobalt.

**Reference**

1. Crystal structure of .mu.-amido-.mu.-superoxo-bis[tetraamminecobalt(III)] tetranitrate, $\ce{[(NH3)4Co(NH2)(O2)Co(NH3)4](NO3)4}$ by
   Gary G. Christoph, Richard E. Marsh, William P. Schaefer, Inorg. Chem. **1969**, 8, 2, 291-297, DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/ic50072a022